# Catching exception without having to throw

Tags: c++, delphi, exception, try-catch

I am new to C++ and I come from a Delphi scenario, in which I was able to catch exceptions even without having to declare an explicit `throw`. Look at here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>

int main() {

 try {

  int c;
  std::cin >> c;

 } catch(...) {

  std::cerr << "Warning!" << std::endl;
  char xz; std::cin >> xz;
  return 1;

 }

 char z; std::cin >> z;
 return 0;

}

//I return 1 because UNIX OS cares about this, a return != 0 means that Huston we have a problem
```

I have seen around that some exception (such as division by zero) aren't automatically caught, so I have to create a `throw` by myself that will be caught for sure in my try-block.

If you look at the code above, when I first input `6.7` or `test` I should be able to see on the output `warning!`, but nothing. I am running on a Windows 10 machine.

I know that the `catch(...)` is the general one and gives me for sure the protection, but why isn't it catching the wrong input?

---

**Note**. I have mentioned Delphi above because if you look at the code below, I am able to catch the error.

```
try

 a := StrToInt('6.78');              //conversion error [string->double], a is int
 ShowMessage('a is ' + a.ToString);

except
 on E: Exception do

 ShowMessage('Warning! > ' + e.Message);
 //^ raises "Warning! > '6.78' is not a valid integer value."

end;
```

Why cannot I produce the same effect with C++? I know that they are two different languages, but at first I'd say that delphi "treats" exceptions better. For example it catches automatically the division by zero (see below) while c++ doesnt.

```
//this raises the "Division by zero" error.
a := 8 div StrToInt('0');
```

---

**Conclusion**. So the questions are: am I declaring the C++ `try-catch` correctly? Do I always have to use the `throw` to be **sure** that the error will be caught or I can omit it some times?

Comment: Catch is an irregular verb, and the 2nd from is caught, not catched. (catch, caught, caught)

Comment: Exceptions work roughly the same in Delphi as they do in C++. You can't catch what is not thrown. Someone has to throw, whether it is you or the libraries you are calling into. Functions like `StrToInt()` have explicit `raise` statements to throw exceptions when they encounter invalid input data. The Delphi RTL also responds to system-generated exceptions (access violation, divide by zero, etc) and converts them into Delphi-style exceptions. That is why you can catch things like `EAccessViolation`, `EDivByZero`, etc.  C++ does not do that conversion, but there are 3rd party libraries that do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::cin` won't throw when the user inputs an invalid type.

Assuming C++11 and higher, the behaviour is as follows:

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

from [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

To check if the input is invalid you should do as follows:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

std::int32_t main()
{
    std::int32_t example;
    std::cin >> example;

    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or you can also do it like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

std::int32_t main()
{
    std::int32_t example;

    if (!(std::cin >> example))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `bool` conversion operators instead, eg: `if (!(std::cin >> example))`.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) you need to set exception mask on `std::cin` to make it throw [`std::ios_base::failure`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cin.exceptions( std::ios::failbit );
    try {
       int i = 0;
       std::cin >> i;
       std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "error!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/2ZwhDq)

> Do I always have to use the throw to be sure that the error will be caught or I can omit it some times?

Yes for exception to be thrown you need to call `throw`. Though libraries may call throw for you for error conditions (including standard one), what exception it may throw and when should be stated in the documentation.